# C# WinForms What type of series in chart control should be used for integer part function?

Tags: c#, winforms, function, charts

[image]

I need to draw the integer part function (function with gaps) in WinForms project on the Chart control. When I try to do in this way:

```
for (int i = -5; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (i < 0)    
    {
        chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, i + 1);
        chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i + 1, i + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, i);
        chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i + 1, i);
    }
}
```

I get ladder. What could you advise me in this case to avoid jumpers?
My result:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the values of x1-x3 and y1,y2, and the result you're getting?

Comment: @Rob, I've added this information in my post

Comment: did you see Gant chart ? https://ganttchart.codeplex.com/ it may be helpfull